# Dispatching Redux Actions from Thunks with IIFEs

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, redux-thunk, reducers

I was wondering if anyone else has seen the pattern of dispatching an action from a thunk as an anonymous IIFE. I do it on some thunks but I wasn't sure if it was considered bad practice, or why it would be. To me it helps keep redundancy out of my action creator naming.

```
const action => dispatch => {
  //some async stuff
  dispatch((()=>({type: ACTION}))())
}
```

this is opposed to the way I see it done nearly everywhere else. Although, to be honest, I haven't found a lot of good opinionated material on action naming and thunk naming and code separation here that I liked.

more typical setup:

```
const action => ({
  type: ACTION
})

const thunkAction => dispatch => {
  dispatch(action())
}
```

the first way just keeps you from having two similarly named functions that are serving basically the same purpose. I am surprised I haven't seen anyone else using that, although maybe I just haven't been using redux for very long. To me this is just a lot easier since in the cases I use this, I would never call the dispatch the action without the thunk. However, maybe this is just a bad practice I am overlooking.

Does anyone know why this would or wouldn't be a bad pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer the first one, why not just

```
const action => dispatch => {
  // some async stuff
  dispatch({ type: ACTION })
}
```

You don't even need to write a function (action creator) for that.

Redux doesn't limit you that you must use action creators. You can always feel free to dispatch an action object directly.

But action creators do have some benefits. Here is the reference for you http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/

Comment: Oh, wow, that makes a lot more sense! *face palm* Thanks for the reference. Definitely over thought that one lol.

Comment: Good answer, and as author of that blog post, glad to know it's helping :)